# iOS11 not taking constraints correctly

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, ios11

I have an app on the store, in order to support all devices and keyboard I am changing the bottom constraint height according to keyboard height. It is working on all iOS versions except on iOS11. The button is not changing its place as it is shown in the below pictures.

Thank you!

this is iOS10 preview
[image: ios10]

this is iOS11 preview
[image: ios11]

**CODE**

```
    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if !keyboardIsHidden{
        return;
    }
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        keyboardIsHidden = false
        nextButtonBottmConstraint.constant = nextButtonBottmConstraint.constant + keyboardSize.height
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us code related to constraint changing.

Comment: the code is added!

Comment: @KingT. i am also facing similar issue in iOS 11 with constraints still searching for solution..

Comment: @Nagarjun Check my answer.

Comment: @RajeshkumarR issue is not with keyboard some constraints are not working in iOS 11.

Comment: @Nagarjun Are you using Top/Bottom LayoutGuide?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR Where exactly to set?

Comment: @Nagarjun If you are using [topLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide) or [bottomLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621504-bottomlayoutguide) you may get autolayout issues in iOS 11.

Comment: No not using it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` to get the keyboard height then change `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

> UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey returns 0 for keyboard rect height
>   value in iOS 11. Changing it to UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey might
>   solve this issue.

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    //Change constraints
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
func keyboardWasShown(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    let info = aNotification.userInfo
    let kbSize: CGSize? = info?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.cgRectValue?.size
    //Change constraints
}
```

Comment: my issue is not related keyboard since the code is working on all iOS versions except iOS 11

Comment: UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey returns 0 for keyboard rect value in iOS 11. Changed it to UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey for a similar issue and it worked.

Comment: @KingT. As thm14 has said `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` returns 0 for keyboard rect value in iOS 11. So `keyboardSize.height`  is equal to 0. Changing `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` will solve your problem. Try it

Comment: @RajeshkumarR I will try it in a while and tell give feedback

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

Use IHKeyboardAvoiding

Step 1) pod 'IHKeyboardAvoiding'

Step 2) Copy the following code

```
 import IHKeyboardAvoiding

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    KeyboardAvoiding.avoidingView = Your_View
  }
```