# Swift keyboard Height return 0

Tags: ios, swift

my code is working fine for the first time when clicking the button I got the keyboard height but the problem is when it dismisses and I call it again it returns hight 0, any help here is the code

```
@IBAction func showCaseProgressSliderBtn(_ sender: Any){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.height
        keyboardHeightCG = keyboardHeight
        print("keyboard is \(keyboardHeightCG)")
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you running this on? I am unable to produce this behavior on device neither on simulator.

Comment: You should replace `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`.

 Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46464774/7250862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about to check it with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` wouldn't this work?